# Browser Path Error after OBIEE 11g Install

Tags: oracle, obiee

I installed OBIEE 11g without any problems until the last step.
Every step was correct, but during the last (14/14) appeared a window with this kind of error: **Browser path Default browser is not found. Enter the browser location**.
I think the installation was successful, but I can't open Analytics, Em and Console maybe for this error. How I can fix it? Thanks

Comment: Which exact "11g" on which exact operating system? Apart from that: that whole product family is outdated and no longer supported.

Comment: Version 11.1.1.9.0 on Linux x-86 64 bit

Comment: And you can't open any of the URLs from the server or from any other random workstation? What browser are you using? And what does the status.sh tell you when you look at the OBI services?

Comment: Every OBI services are Alive. I can't open with every browser from the URLs of Analytics, EM and Console.

Comment: See above: "from the server or from any other random workstation"? I.e. is it a browser issues or a network issue or what? Does your server browser actually work wto open anything else? Does some other workstation vrowser trying to access OBI also throw that same error? The error message sounds like nothing related to OBI at all